# ListBox selected index color wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, selectedindex

I am just starting with WPF and I have this `ListBox` that displays an attribute 
from a class I made. I have to programmatically change the selected index, when I do something like:

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 4;
```

the `SelectedIndex` is changed and highlighted gray, but if I click on it, the selected index is blue.  Is there something else i need to do to have both behave the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the focus is not on the `ListBox`. Try `ListBox1.Focus()` after changing the `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: huh...yeah that works, I imagine that's consistent behavior across all the controls. Changing attributes programmatically doesn't give them the focus. 
Thank you